# How can i automatically update a user control without updating the whole asp.netpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

How can i automatically update a user control after a specific time without updating the whole aspx page. I haven't done it before. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose you are using asp.net ajax and it has timer control.
check this example : http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/ and this video : http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control .

Answer (score 1):

If you have the AJAX extension installed, you can use an UpdatePanel and the ContentTemplate to only refresh that region of your webpage when performing a Postback. You can put any content here, as a self created Usercontrol.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="Server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="Server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Click Me Again" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The idea would then be to use a Timer to perform a Postback of that UpdatePanel, as someone else has suggested a link for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean when you say "updating" but if you take a look at the life cycle of an active server page you will see that the whole page will be "refreshed" by the web server.

When the web server responds to a client request the entire content will be transformed to a page displayable by a browser and send to the client.

Comment: i want to update only some controls on my web page likea label displaying current time on server

Comment: Okay, if you want to display the current time you should take a look at the DateTime-Class. Yet the user will have to refresh the entire page (pressing F5) to display the current time.